# Polymer use different behavior based on property selection

Tags: javascript, polymer, difference

is it possible to decide which behavior to use in my polymer element ? maybe like this

```
function select_between_a_b(property_name) {
  return property_name = 'a' ? behavior_a : behavior_b;
}

Polymer({
  is:'test-element', 
  properties: {
    selectorProperty: {
      type: String,
      value: 'a',
    }
  },
  behaviors: [select_between_a_b('selectorProperty')]
});
```

or something like that ... i have one markup/template but want to use different function on them selected by a property...

Comment: As far as I know, what you're trying to do is impossible considering that behaviors are the closest thing Polymer currently has to inheritance in an OOP-sense, you should probably go around this other way depending on what use case you have here

Answer (score -1):

I'm discovering polymer too so i may be wrong.

Following the doc you can. Here is there example.

```
<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'x-custom',

    properties: {
      user: String,
      manager: {
        type: Boolean,
        notify: true
      }
    },

    attached: function() {
      // render
      this.textContent = 'Hello World, my user is ' + (this.user || 'nobody') + '.\n' +
        'This user is ' + (this.manager ? '' : 'not') + ' a manager.';
    }

  });

</script>

<x-custom user="Scott" manager></x-custom>
```

So you are able to use a propertie base on the custom dom as the user="Scott" showing

Source: [polymer attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-deserialization)

Comment: this is nice to know but in doesn't answer my question sorry.  But thank you.